# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to call a Spring Boot controller from a Ajax Request:

```
 $('#female').click(function(){
   $('#analysisTable').DataTable( {
     "ajax": '/analyse/female'
   });
 });
```

The Idea behind this is to load a list into a js datatable.
The controller looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/analyse/female")
public List<GenderAnalysis> analysisByFemale(final Model model) {
    final List<GenderAnalysis> result = analyseDao.getAnalysisByGender(AnalyseDAO.Gender.Female);
    return result;
}
```

The controller works fine. But i get an Thymeleaf Template error. 
Every response will be handled through a ThymeleafLayoutInterceptor and load "normal" (not ajax) requests into a template.

The erorr is the following:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/analyse/female.html]")
```

I know that there is not a female.html resource and i even won't have one. Just serve the raw List to ajax call.

I'm not sure how to work with Spring Boot+Thymeleaf+Ajax even with templates.
Could it be a handling problem with the interceptor? What can i do? Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return JSON rather than a Thymeleaf template, you should either:

1) Declare the controller as a `@RestController` rather than just a `@Controller`.  This will affect all `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` and `@RequestMapping` annotations on your controller class.

or

2) Declare the method as a `@ResponseBody` in addition to the `@GetMapping`.

```
@GetMapping("/analyse/female")
@ResponseBody
public List<GenderAnalysis> analysisByFemale() {
    return analyseDao.getAnalysisByGender(AnalyseDAO.Gender.Female);
}
```